# Trying to find a special algorithm for a quite complex problem

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization

I need to write an algorithm, that lengthens or shortens sticks in order to meet certain requirements.

So, there is a number of sticks given. Each stick has a length (e.g., 1.43 m), a tolerance it can be longer (e.g., 0.02 m) and tolerance the stick can be shorter (e.g., 0.01 m). All lengths and tolerances are multiples of 0.01 m, so for example a stick cannot have the length 1.435 m.

The algorithm needs to adjust the length of the sticks so that for any specific length the following requirements are met:

- if the length is no multiple of 0.1 m (e.g., 1.67 m), there must be at least 10 sticks or none
- if the length is a multiple of 0.1 m (e.g., 2.40 m) there can be any number of sticks

In other words: If the length (format: x.xx m) doesn't end with a zero, there must be at least 10 or no stick with that length in the final distribution; if it does, you can have any number of sticks.

The algorithm should find a distributions of stick lengths so that:

- as many sticks as possible meet the above requirements without leaving their tolerance range; if some sticks cannot meet the the requirements they need to be lengthened or shortened outside their tolerance range - the goal is to keep the total length of sticks outside their tolerance area as low as possible
- (optionally) prefer lengthening over shortening

The total number of sticks can be up to multiple thousands and the algorithm should need at most a couple of minutes to find the best distribution.

Example:
There is the following stick distribution:

- 2x 1.56 m (2x +0.02 m -0.01 m)
- 4x 1.74 m (2x +0.01 m -0.04 m; 2x +0.03 m -0.05 m)
- 9x 1.77 m (9x +0.02 m -0.01 m)

All of the above sticks don't have a multiple of 0.1 m length and there are fewer than 10 stick at any length. So this distribution is not compatible with the requirements.

The algorithm should find the following optimal distribution:

- 2x 1.60 m
- 2x 1.70 m
- 11x 1.77 m

Now the new distribution ist compatible with the requirements. There are two sticks at 1.60 m and 1.70 m; this is fine, as this is a multiple of 0.1 m length. And there are 11 Sticks at 1.77 m; this is also fine, because there are at least 10 Sticks.

What I have done:

- The two 1.56 m sticks were extended to 1.60 m. This is outside of their tolerance, but there was no better option.
- The two sticks with a length of 1.74 and a tolerance of +0.01 m and -0.04 were shortend to 1.70 m; they couldn't be lengthend to 1.77 m, which is preferred over shortening, because their positive tolerance is to small. However, they could be easily shortend to 1.70 m within their tolerance.
- The other two sticks at 1.74 m with a tolerance of +0.03 m and -0.05 m could be lengthend to 1.77 m, so there are 11 sticks with that length; they could also be shortend to 1.70 m, but firstly, lengthening is preferred over shortening and secondly, then the 9 sticks with 1.77 m length need to be lengthend outside of their tolerance.

I thought about it for a long time and tried to figure out an algorithm myself, but I couldn't find one. Maybe my problem is similar to curve fitting, but I don't know how to apply this to my problem.

I would be very happy if someone could help me to find an appropriate algorithm or tell me a similar algorithm that can be adapted to my problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello, I'm a bit unclear on your example. It seems to me that the algorithm could just leave the lengths unmodified: `2x 1.56 m, 4x 1.74 m, 9x 1.77 m`, this way we definitely have "at least 10 sticks with length no multiple of 0.1m".

Comment: @Stef 1.56 is not multiple of 0.1m. Though 1.77 is not too. If I understood OP correctly.

Comment: @GuruStron Yes, I can agree with you that 1.56 is not multiple of 0.1m. That doesn't remove my confusion at all.

Comment: @Stef I think the idea is that group should have 10+ elements if it is not multiple of 0.1. i.e. 1,77 if fine with 11 sticks but 1.56 is not with 2.

Comment: @GuruStron Perhaps we could let the OP clarify the problem.

Comment: Also there appears to be an issue with the input: `9x 1.77 m (7x +0.02 m -0.01 m)`. There's two missing sticks.

Comment: @Stef 2 missed sticks were moved from 1.74 to get the output.

Comment: @GuruStron I'm talking about the input, not the output. Your guesses are very interesting, but I would really like a clarification from the OP.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help! @Stef, the requirements are meant per length. In other words: If the length (format: x.xx m) doesn't end with a zero, there must be at least 10 or no stick with that length in the final distribution; if it does, you can have any number of sticks. And as you pointed out, there is a mistake in my input. It should also be 9 sticks in the parentheses. I will update my Question and clarify these two things. I will also explain my example.

Comment: For future reference, on StackOverflow, a well formed question will attempt a solution with code.

Comment: I disagree with ryanwebjackson's comment above, in this case an attempted code inside the question post would just have distracted from the problem.

Comment: If that's the case, then it belongs on another site, where the algorithm can be determined first. StackOverlow is not an algorithm writing service, in the same way it's not a code writing service.

Comment: @ryanwebjackson https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @tevemadar I'm aware that discussing an algorithm is on topic, but my point is that a solution should be attempted and detailed first, in the same way that code would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to build an integer linear program, by:

- Build the list of possible target lengths;
- Have a binary decision variable for each pair (input stick, target length);
- Incur a penalty if stick i is assigned to target length j and target j is outside of stick i's tolerance

We want to reach a valid combination of lengths, while minimising the penalty.

The objective function is the sum of the penalties.

There are two types of constraints:

- The constraints "stick i is assigned to exactly one target length" for all stick i;
- The constraints "target length j is assigned to 0 or >=10 sticks" for all each non-multiple-of-10 target length j.

```py
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter
from pulp import LpProblem, LpMinimize, LpVariable, lpSum

# all lengths in centimeters
#data: [(length, minus_tol, plus_tol, number), ...]
data = [(156, 1, 2, 2), (174, 4, 1, 2), (174, 5, 3, 2), (177, 1, 2, 9)]

minimum = min(l - m for (l,m,_,_) in data)  # 155
maximum = max(l + p for (l,_,p,_) in data)  # 179
lengths = list(set(l for (l,_,_,_) in data))
targets = lengths + list(range(10*(minimum//10), 10*((maximum+9)//10)+1, 10))
# targets = [177, 156, 174, 150, 160, 170, 180]

def calculate_weight(u, v, shortening_penalty=2):
    l,m,p,i = u
    t = v
    if t > l+p:
        return (t - (l+p))**2
    elif t < l-m:
        return ((l-m) - t)**2 * shortening_penalty
    else:
        return 0

left_nodes = list(chain.from_iterable(((l,m,p,i) for i in range(n)) for (l,m,p,n) in data))
right_nodes = targets # [(t, l) for t in targets for l in left_nodes]
weight = [[calculate_weight(u, v) for v in right_nodes] for u in left_nodes]

prob = LpProblem("Sticks", LpMinimize)

## VARIABLES

# assign stick i to length j
X = [[LpVariable(f'x({i},{j})', cat='Binary') for j in range(len(right_nodes))]
             for i in range(len(left_nodes))]
# decide whether length j has 0 or >=10 sticks
F = [LpVariable(f'f{j}', cat='Binary') for j in range(len(lengths))]


## OBJECTIVE
prob += lpSum(X[i][j] * weight[i][j] for j in range(len(right_nodes)) for i in range(len(left_nodes))), 'Total penalty for assignment'


## CONSTRAINTS

for i in range(len(left_nodes)):
    prob += lpSum(X[i][j] for j in range(len(right_nodes))) == 1, f'Stick {i} is assigned to one final length'

M = len(left_nodes) + 1
for j in range(len(lengths)):
    if lengths[j] % 10 != 0:
        prob += lpSum(X[i][j] for i in range(len(left_nodes))) <= M * F[j], f'if 0 sticks for target length {j}'
        prob += lpSum(X[i][j] for i in range(len(left_nodes))) >= 10 * F[j], f'if 10 sticks for target length {j}'


## SOLUTION

prob.solve()

final_lengths = Counter(l for j,l in enumerate(targets) for i in range(len(left_nodes)) if X[i][j].varValue)

print('FINAL SOLUTION:')
print(final_lengths)
```

This prints the following solution:

```
FINAL SOLUTION:
Counter({177: 10, 170: 3, 160: 2})
```

Comment: Technically the integer problem I wrote is not completely equivalent to the original problem, because my list of lengths `targets` is not exhaustive enough. This can be fixed by including more target lengths at the beginning: Instead of `lengths = list(set(l for (l,_,_,_) in data))` at the beginning, it should be `lengths = list(set(chain.from_iterable((l-m, l, l+p) for (l,m,p,_) in data)))`

Comment: For instance, with 9 sticks (153, -1, +1) and 1 stick (151, -1, +1), then my program above would miss the solution with 10 sticks at 152, because 152 would not be in the target lengths.

Comment: thank you for your great answer and your clarification; If I understand it correctly, if I replace the `lengths  = ` part from the original answer with your new line provided in your comment, then the algorithm is exactly what I was looking for. Or are there any known downsides in the new approach?

Comment: @MarcAltmann Yes you understand correctly. The downside is that this will increase the number of target lengths, which might slow down the solver algorithm. I can't really tell by how much it would slow it down.

Comment: @MarcAltmann Also, your description of the problem says *"(optionally) prefer lengthening over shortening"*. In my code, I've translated that to an increased penalty if we shorten a stick to below its lower tolerance, as you can see in `calculate_weight`. But maybe you want a penalty even if we shorten inside the tolerance? In that case you should add a case in `calculate_weight`, something like `elif t < l: return (l - t)**2 * some_coefficient`

Comment: yes, actually I want to prefer lengthening over shortening even inside the tolerance area. Thank you for additional clarification, this helps a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I demonstrate an alternative LP implementation that is much more "manual", in other words, it sets up the linear constraint matrices directly. It successfully finds a solution to your original problem, as well as an augmented problem that has up to two groups. Details in the comments. Conversion of the constraint matrices to sparse is left as an exercise for the reader.

```py
from typing import Any

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.optimize
from scipy.optimize import Bounds, LinearConstraint, OptimizeResult

'''
the total number of sticks is fixed
the lower and upper tolerances for each instance are fixed
for a given output value, either it must have at least 10 instances, or it must be a multiple of 10cm
passing the minimum is very costly
passing the maximum is less costly

decision variables:
for each stick length, a lower and upper minimised slack variable
n decimetre-resolution lengths, integral
n centimetre-resolution lengths, integral
n*(n/10) group assignment booleans
n/10 group-enable booleans
n/10 group centimetre lengths
'''


def setup(centre: np.ndarray, lotol: np.ndarray, hitol: np.ndarray) -> tuple[
    dict[str, Any],  # milp parameters
    dict[str, Any],  # setup variables
]:
    n_loslacks = n_hislacks = n_dm_lengths = n_cm_lengths = len(centre)
    n_group_lengths = n_group_enables = n_cm_lengths//10
    n_group_assignments = n_cm_lengths*n_group_enables

    i_loslacks = 0
    i_hislacks = i_loslacks + n_loslacks
    i_dm_lengths = i_hislacks + n_hislacks
    i_cm_lengths = i_dm_lengths + n_dm_lengths
    i_group_assignments = i_cm_lengths + n_cm_lengths
    i_group_enables = i_group_assignments + n_group_assignments
    i_group_lengths = i_group_enables + n_group_enables

    c = np.zeros(
        shape=n_loslacks + n_hislacks + n_dm_lengths + n_cm_lengths + n_group_assignments + n_group_enables + n_group_lengths,
        dtype=int,
    )
    c[i_loslacks: i_loslacks+n_loslacks] = 2  # exceeding the lower tolerance is more costly
    c[i_hislacks: i_hislacks+n_hislacks] = 1  # exceeding the upper tolerance is less costly

    integrality = np.ones_like(c)  # all decision and auxiliary variables are integral

    x_lower = np.zeros_like(c)
    x_lower[i_dm_lengths: i_dm_lengths+n_dm_lengths] = 1  # 10 cm
    x_lower[i_cm_lengths: i_cm_lengths+n_cm_lengths] = 1  # 1 cm
    x_lower[i_group_lengths: i_group_lengths+n_group_lengths] = 1  # 1 cm
    x_upper = np.full(c.size, np.inf)
    x_upper[i_group_enables: i_group_enables+n_group_enables] = 1  # the enables are boolean
    x_upper[i_group_assignments: i_group_assignments+n_group_assignments] = 1  # the assignments are boolean

    # The low slack variable "pushing" the length up from the lower bound
    # loslack >= -cm + centre - lotol
    A_loslack = np.hstack((
        np.eye(n_loslacks, dtype=int),
        np.zeros((n_loslacks, n_hislacks + n_dm_lengths), dtype=int),
        np.eye(n_cm_lengths, dtype=int),
        np.zeros((n_loslacks, n_group_assignments + n_group_enables + n_group_lengths), dtype=int),
    ))
    l_loslack = centre - lotol
    u_loslack = np.full(n_loslacks, np.inf)

    # The high slack variable "pushing" the length down from the upper bound
    # hislack >= cm - centre - hitol
    A_hislack = np.hstack((
        np.zeros((n_hislacks, n_hislacks), dtype=int),
        -np.eye(n_hislacks, dtype=int),
        np.zeros((n_hislacks, n_dm_lengths), dtype=int),
        np.eye(n_cm_lengths, dtype=int),
        np.zeros((n_hislacks, n_group_assignments + n_group_enables + n_group_lengths), dtype=int),
    ))
    l_hislack = -u_loslack
    u_hislack = centre + hitol

    # Each stick must be assigned to at most one group
    A_ugroup = np.hstack((
        np.zeros((n_cm_lengths, n_loslacks + n_hislacks + n_dm_lengths + n_cm_lengths), dtype=int),
        np.repeat(np.eye(n_cm_lengths, dtype=int), repeats=n_group_enables, axis=1),
        np.zeros((n_cm_lengths, n_group_enables + n_group_lengths), dtype=int),
    ))
    l_ugroup = np.zeros(n_cm_lengths, dtype=int)
    u_ugroup = np.ones(n_cm_lengths, dtype=int)

    # if a stick is not assigned to a group, its length must be a dm multiple
    # 0 <= buffer*assignment + 10*dm_length - cmlength
    # 0 <= buffer*assignment - 10*dm_length + cmlength
    # buffer > largest cm_length - smallest dm_length
    dm_buffer = 15
    A_dm_cm_lo = np.hstack((
        np.zeros((n_cm_lengths, n_loslacks + n_hislacks), dtype=int),
        10*np.eye(n_dm_lengths, dtype=int),
        -np.eye(n_cm_lengths, dtype=int),
        np.repeat(dm_buffer * np.eye(n_cm_lengths, dtype=int), repeats=n_group_enables, axis=1),
        np.zeros((n_cm_lengths, n_group_enables + n_group_lengths), dtype=int),
    ))
    A_dm_cm_hi = np.hstack((
        np.zeros((n_cm_lengths, n_loslacks + n_hislacks), dtype=int),
        -10*np.eye(n_dm_lengths, dtype=int),
        np.eye(n_cm_lengths, dtype=int),
        np.repeat(dm_buffer * np.eye(n_cm_lengths, dtype=int), repeats=n_group_enables, axis=1),
        np.zeros((n_cm_lengths, n_group_enables + n_group_lengths), dtype=int),
    ))
    l_dm_cm = np.zeros(n_cm_lengths, dtype=int)
    u_dm_cm = np.full(n_cm_lengths, np.inf)

    # If a group is active, it must have at least 10 assignments
    # 0 <= 10*active <= asnsum
    A_group_count_lo = np.hstack((
        np.zeros((n_group_enables, i_group_assignments), dtype=int),
        np.tile(np.eye(n_group_enables, dtype=int), (1, n_cm_lengths)),
        -10*np.eye(n_group_enables, dtype=int),
        np.zeros((n_group_enables, n_group_lengths), dtype=int),
    ))
    l_group_count_lo = np.zeros(n_group_enables, dtype=int)
    u_group_count_lo = np.full(n_group_enables, np.inf)

    # If a group is inactive, it must have no assignments
    # 0 <= asnsum <= buffer*active
    group_buffer = 10*n_group_enables
    A_group_count_hi = np.hstack((
        np.zeros((n_group_enables, i_group_assignments), dtype=int),
        np.tile(-np.eye(n_group_enables, dtype=int), (1, n_cm_lengths)),
        group_buffer*np.eye(n_group_enables, dtype=int),
        np.zeros((n_group_enables, n_group_lengths), dtype=int),
    ))
    l_group_count_hi = l_group_count_lo
    u_group_count_hi = u_group_count_lo

    # if a given cm group is assigned to a stick, cm length must equal group length
    # 0 <= buffer*(1-assignment) + cm - group_length    assignment*buffer - cm + group_length <= buffer
    # 0 <= buffer*(1-assignment) - cm + group_length    assignment*buffer + cm - group_length <= buffer
    cm_buffer = 10 * (centre.max() - centre.min() + hitol.max() - lotol.max())
    A_group_eq_lo = np.hstack((
        np.zeros((n_group_assignments, i_cm_lengths), dtype=int),
        np.repeat(-np.eye(n_cm_lengths, dtype=int), n_group_enables, axis=0),
        cm_buffer*np.eye(n_group_assignments, dtype=int),
        np.zeros((n_group_assignments, n_group_enables), dtype=int),
        np.tile(np.eye(n_group_lengths, dtype=int), (n_cm_lengths, 1))
    ))
    A_group_eq_hi = np.hstack((
        np.zeros((n_group_assignments, i_cm_lengths), dtype=int),
        np.repeat(np.eye(n_cm_lengths, dtype=int), n_group_enables, axis=0),
        cm_buffer*np.eye(n_group_assignments, dtype=int),
        np.zeros((n_group_assignments, n_group_enables), dtype=int),
        np.tile(-np.eye(n_group_lengths, dtype=int), (n_cm_lengths, 1))
    ))
    l_group_eq = np.full(n_group_assignments, -np.inf)
    u_group_eq = np.full(n_group_assignments, cm_buffer)

    A = np.vstack      ((A_loslack, A_hislack, A_ugroup, A_dm_cm_lo, A_dm_cm_hi, A_group_count_lo, A_group_count_hi, A_group_eq_lo, A_group_eq_hi,))
    lb = np.concatenate((l_loslack, l_hislack, l_ugroup, l_dm_cm,    l_dm_cm,    l_group_count_lo, l_group_count_hi, l_group_eq,    l_group_eq,   ))
    ub = np.concatenate((u_loslack, u_hislack, u_ugroup, u_dm_cm,    u_dm_cm,    u_group_count_lo, u_group_count_hi, u_group_eq,    u_group_eq,   ))

    return {
        'c': c,
        'integrality': integrality,
        'bounds': Bounds(lb=x_lower, ub=x_upper),
        'constraints': LinearConstraint(A=A, lb=lb, ub=ub),
    }, locals()


def run(**params: Any) -> OptimizeResult:
    result = scipy.optimize.milp(**params)
    assert result.success
    return result


def display(
    result: OptimizeResult,
    setup_vars: dict[str, Any],
    centre: np.ndarray, lotol: np.ndarray, hitol: np.ndarray,
) -> None:
    stick_df = pd.DataFrame(
        result.x[:setup_vars['i_group_assignments']]
        .reshape((-1, setup_vars['n_cm_lengths']))
        .round().astype(int)
        .T,
        columns=('loslack', 'hislack', 'dm', 'cm'),
    )
    stick_df['centre'] = centre
    stick_df['lot'] = lotol
    stick_df['hit'] = hitol
    stick_df[[f'g{i}' for i in range(setup_vars['n_group_enables'])]] = result.x[
        setup_vars['i_group_assignments']:
        setup_vars['i_group_assignments'] + setup_vars['n_group_assignments']
    ].reshape((-1, setup_vars['n_group_enables'])).round().astype(int)

    group_df = pd.DataFrame(
        result.x[setup_vars['i_group_enables']:]
        .reshape((-1, setup_vars['n_group_enables']))
        .astype(int).T,
        columns=('enable', 'cm')
    )
    group_df[[f'l{i}' for i in range(setup_vars['n_cm_lengths'])]] = result.x[
        setup_vars['i_group_assignments']:
        setup_vars['i_group_assignments'] + setup_vars['n_group_assignments']
    ].reshape((-1, setup_vars['n_group_enables'])).T.round().astype(int)

    pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
    pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 50)

    print(result.message)
    print(stick_df)
    print(group_df)
    print()


def test(data: np.ndarray) -> None:
    centre, lotol, hitol = data.T
    params, setup_vars = setup(centre, lotol, hitol)
    result = run(**params)
    display(result, setup_vars, centre, lotol, hitol)


def op_test() -> None:
    """
    2x 1.56 m (2x +0.02 m -0.01 m)
    4x 1.74 m (2x +0.01 m -0.04 m; 2x +0.03 m -0.05 m)
    9x 1.77 m (9x +0.02 m -0.01 m)
    """
    test(np.array((
        (156, 1, 2),
        (156, 1, 2),
        (174, 4, 1),
        (174, 4, 1),
        (174, 5, 3),
        (174, 5, 3),
        (177, 1, 2),
        (177, 1, 2),
        (177, 1, 2),
        (177, 1, 2),
        (177, 1, 2),
        (177, 1, 2),
        (177, 1, 2),
        (177, 1, 2),
        (177, 1, 2),
    )))


def augmented_op_test() -> None:
    test(np.array((
        (156, 1, 2),
        (156, 1, 2),
        (174, 4, 1),
        (174, 4, 1),
        (174, 5, 3),
        (174, 5, 3),
        (177, 1, 2),
        (177, 1, 2),
        (177, 1, 2),
        (177, 1, 2),
        (177, 1, 2),
        (177, 1, 2),
        (177, 1, 2),
        (177, 1, 2),
        (177, 1, 2),
        # following added to produce up to two groups of 10
        (175, 3, 1),
        (175, 3, 1),
        (175, 3, 1),
        (175, 3, 1),
        (175, 3, 1),
        (175, 3, 1),
        (175, 3, 1),
        (175, 3, 1),
    )))


def main() -> None:
    op_test()
    augmented_op_test()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
Optimization terminated successfully. (HiGHS Status 7: Optimal)
    loslack  hislack  dm   cm  centre  lot  hit  g0
0         0        2  16  160     156    1    2   0
1         0        2  16  160     156    1    2   0
2         0        0  17  170     174    4    1   0
3         0        0  17  170     174    4    1   0
4         0        0  17  176     174    5    3   1
5         0        0  17  170     174    5    3   0
6         0        0  17  176     177    1    2   1
7         0        0  17  176     177    1    2   1
8         0        0  17  176     177    1    2   1
9         0        0  17  176     177    1    2   1
10        0        0  17  176     177    1    2   1
11        0        0  17  176     177    1    2   1
12        0        0  17  176     177    1    2   1
13        0        0  17  176     177    1    2   1
14        0        0  17  176     177    1    2   1
   enable   cm  l0  l1  l2  l3  l4  l5  l6  l7  l8  l9  l10  l11  l12  l13  l14
0       1  176   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   1   1    1    1    1    1    1

Optimization terminated successfully. (HiGHS Status 7: Optimal)
    loslack  hislack  dm   cm  centre  lot  hit  g0  g1
0         0        2  16  160     156    1    2   0   0
1         0        2  16  160     156    1    2   0   0
2         0        0  17  170     174    4    1   0   0
3         0        0  17  170     174    4    1   0   0
4         0        0  17  170     174    5    3   0   0
5         0        0  17  170     174    5    3   0   0
6         0        0  17  176     177    1    2   1   0
7         0        0  17  176     177    1    2   1   0
8         0        0  17  176     177    1    2   1   0
9         0        0  17  176     177    1    2   1   0
10        0        0  17  176     177    1    2   1   0
11        0        0  17  176     177    1    2   1   0
12        0        0  17  176     177    1    2   1   0
13        0        0  17  176     177    1    2   1   0
14        0        0  17  176     177    1    2   1   0
15        0        0  17  176     175    3    1   1   0
16        0        0  17  176     175    3    1   1   0
17        0        0  17  176     175    3    1   1   0
18        0        0  17  176     175    3    1   1   0
19        0        0  17  176     175    3    1   1   0
20        0        0  17  176     175    3    1   1   0
21        0        0  17  176     175    3    1   1   0
22        0        0  17  176     175    3    1   1   0
   enable   cm  l0  l1  l2  l3  l4  l5  l6  l7  l8  l9  l10  l11  l12  l13  l14  l15  l16  l17  l18  l19  l20  l21  l22
0       1  176   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
1       0   30   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```